# RMI cllient reconnect gives java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table

Tags: java, rmi

ill try to explain my setting.

Setting:
i run 1 "server"(note: not rmi server) who is always up.
When i run 1 client, the client creates an rmi host like so:

```
       String bindLocation = "//localhost/ntn";
       try { 
          registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            Naming.bind(bindLocation, ntn);


        } catch (MalformedURLException | AlreadyBoundException e) {}
```

And the server starts acting as a RMI client like so:

```
          try {
              name = "//localhost/ntn";
              ntnI = null;
              ntnI = (NodeToNodeInterface) Naming.lookup(name);
              ntnI.serverAnswer(k);
              k++;
          } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("FileServer exception: "+ e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

This all works. But after that the client has received the "server answer" it unbinds like so:

```
    try { 
        Naming.unbind(bindLocation);
        UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(registry,true);   
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {}
```

Now if i Open a seccond client(same code as client 1) it again start to act as a RMI server on the same name and port. if this is set up de same function runs on the server and gives the following error:

```
    java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
```

wich points to the line:

```
              ntnI = (NodeToNodeInterface) Naming.lookup(name);
```

How do i reinitialise it? or how to fix this?
Normally the RMI server is perfectly setup before the server(RMIclient) uses the serverAnswer function.(and it works teh first time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't unexport the registry, and don't create it when you bind. Create it first and leave it there for the life of the JVM. Otherwise there is nothing for `Naming.lookup()` to talk to.

Comment: this worked thenks, had to put the registery and the naming in 2 separate catches